# How to get Stripe tax ids by value

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

I am trying to query Stripe for tax ids by value for verifying if someone has already registered with that tax id. I cannot get tax ids listed any way I try. My code is in C#, but an answer in any other language would be helpful. My code below returns null exception, of not much help

```
        public async Task<StripeList<TaxId>?> GetTaxIds(string value)
        {
            try
            {
                var options = new TaxIdListOptions()
                {
                    ExtraParams = new Dictionary<string, object> {
                       {  "value", value }
                   }
                };
                var service = new TaxIdService();
                return await service.ListAsync(String.Empty, options);
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Another solution would be to search for customers with the given tax id using the Stripe query language, something like this:

```
        var options = new CustomerSearchOptions
        {
            Query = $"tax_ids CONTAINS '{value}'",
        };
```

A solution on how to get customers by tax_id would also be great.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

TaxIdService is related to listing TaxIds for a certain customer as described [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_tax_ids/list?lang=dotnet). You need to [list](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/list?lang=dotnet) all Customers and [expand](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects?lang=dotnet) on [["tax_ids"]](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object?lang=dotnet#customer_object-tax_ids). You might need to use [auto-pagination](https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto?lang=dotnet) as well since you're looping over all your customers.